# Scrollable div with constrained height and overflow:auto doesn't scroll with touch (Chrome & Safari only)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, touch, mobile-safari

I have a container div with fixed position to be sticky to the top & bottom of the screen. Within that container, I have a div that is scrollable:

```
.content-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.inner-scroll-pane {        
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This works well on all desktop browsers (with mouse wheel or touchpad). However, the .inner-scroll-pane div doesn't scroll properly on touch screens (mobile browsers as well as touch laptops).

Panning the inner div doesn't scroll at first - instead it tries to pan the whole page, which just over-bounces (since it's fixed to the size of the screen and doesn't have anything to scroll). If I first tap a control in the .inner-scroll-pane div, putting focus within, then touch panning works perfectly and the div scrolls.

(Further, this problem only happens with Chrome or Safari on touch screens. Firefox & IE on touch screens work.)

Based on [this post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/05/IPad-Scroll-Issues-with-Fixed-Content), I tried changing the container to position: absolute but it didn't make a difference.

How can I make the inner div scroll on touch screens?

UPDATE: On further investigation, it doesn't seem that the position: fixed parent is the problem specifically (just indirectly contributing). This problem happens because the .inner-scroll-pane div has a constrained height and then uses overflow: auto (overflow: scroll also has the same issue). I've updated the title...

So, how do I get touch panning to work immediately on a div with constrained height and overflow? (without first tapping/putting focus within the div)

Comment: What kind of content is inside the .inner-scroll-pane? Why does it need the height to be 100%? It would make more sense to me to have the .content-container 100% width and height and overflow-y: auto, and then the .inner-scroll-pane have overflow:hidden. As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/emilcieslar/24eky2as/